# Help with meta-regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I want to implement a meta-regression and require some assistance. Suppose that two univariate features ($X$ and $Y$) were measured from two samples $A$ and $B$ of size $N_A$ and $N_B$, respectively. Both $A$ and $B$ come from the same population, such that $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables which are identically distributed. For $A$, I have the regression coefficients associated with the equation $Y_A=X_A\beta_{1,A} + \beta_{0,A}$. Similarly, for $B$, I have the regression coefficients associated with the equation $Y_B=X_B\beta_{1,B} + \beta_{0,B}$. I also have the means $\bar X_A$, $\bar X_B$,  $\bar Y_A$, $\bar Y_B$ and their estimated variances $s^2 (X_A)$, $s^2 (X_B)$,  $s^2 (Y_A)$, $s^2 (Y_B)$. All regression coefficients have the same units. I want to calculate the regression coefficients for the combined sample $C=A\cup B$, i.e. for the equation $Y_C=X_C\beta_{1,C} + \beta_{0,C}$. How can I do this if I do not have access to the actual data?

Comment: Not so simple. That depends if sample A is plausibly from the same population as sample B or not. So is it?

Comment: Yes, they are from the same population.

Comment: How do you know? Did you test  for significant difference?

Comment: I implemented a test of heterogeneity and obtained a p value close to 1. The two samples come from studies with the same inclusion/exclusion criteria, the measurements of $X$ and $Y$ were made using a very similar protocol. Eventually, I will likely run into studies where the null hypothesis of the heterogeneity test is rejected at a significant level, but for now I'd like to combine these two studies because they have a large sample size and they are the studies that interest me most.

Comment: So combine the parameters.

Comment: Here is a simple way. Plot 20 pairs of solutions to both regression equations and fit a regression to those pairs.

Comment: But you have to weight each member of each pair by their respective $n$-values.

Comment: Thank you, Carl. Isn't the regression coefficient $\beta_{1,C}$ equal to the weighted average of the regression coefficients for the individual regressions?

Comment: In effect, to find the slope and intercept, you could enter the same values 10 times for $n_1=10$, and 20 times for $n_2=20$ and then perform OLS regression. However, that would not allow one to solve for the correct errors of the slope and intercept.

Comment: am not clear about the end structure of your Combined Equation. Moreover, I need an understanding of objectives of your study.

Comment: @carl Thank you for these suggestions!
The objective is to calculate the coefficient $\beta_{1,C}$ for the combined sample. The value of this coefficient is of interest in and of itself. As stated in the statement of the problem, the combined equation for the larger sample is a simple linear regression equation, just like in the case of the two smaller samples. The same type of regression is applied to all samples.

Comment: The equation YA=XAβ1,A+β0,A  does not represent linear regression model.  Moreover, it is not desireable to run meta-regression or even meta- analysis when the" effect-sizes" have been calculated as regression coefficients. These are based on several statistical assumption including probability statistics. May be you could combine mean estimates (and variance estimates)  separately.But I am handicapped/not sure of a procedure's availabity.

Comment: I realize now that I forgot to add an error term to my equation so that it matches the formula for linear regression. Thank you for that correction. There is a lot of literature on the use of regression coefficients as measures of effect size in a meta-analysis. It’s certainly not the most common way to quantify effect size, but it it is not unheard of. Typically, standardized regression coefficients are used when this is done. For what I’m interested in, the value of the regression coefficient is of greatest interest, so the regression coefficient is what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that I forgot to add an error term to my equation so that it matches the formula for linear regression. Thank you for that correction.

There is a lot of literature on the use of regression coefficients as measures of effect size in a meta-analysis. It’s certainly not the most common way to quantify effect size, but it it is not unheard of. Typically, standardized regression coefficients are used when this is done. For the application I’m interested in, the value of the regression coefficient is of greatest practical interest to begin with, and so the regression coefficient is what I decided to use.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.